# Do 2 things on if statement =

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, rename, user-input, goto

I want to do 2 things if a statement equals a value, I am looking to rename then goto.

Any recommendations MUCH appreciated!

```
:BRAND
echo.
echo What brand are you staging?
echo.
echo          T = BRAND1
echo.
echo          M = BRAND2
echo.
echo          P = BRAND3
echo.
SET /P BRAND=T/M/P? 

IF /I '%BRAND%'=='T' REN C:\U.bmp V.bmp /y **THEN GOTO OK**
IF /I '%BRAND%'=='M' REN C:\W.bmp X.bmp /y  **THEN GOTO OK**
IF /I '%BRAND%'=='P' REN C:\Y.bmp Z.bmp /y  **THEN GOTO OK**

:OK
```

Comment: ALSO, I need to take it a step further and rename 2 files vs. the 1 then GOTO statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your purposes, you really don't need the `GOTO`. But, if you need to do more than two things and/or keep things more readable, you can do this too:

```
IF /I '%BRAND%'=='T' (
  REN C:\U.bmp V.bmp /y
  GOTO OK
)
IF /I '%BRAND%'=='M' (
  REN C:\W.bmp X.bmp /y
  GOTO OK
)
IF /I '%BRAND%'=='P' (
  REN C:\Y.bmp Z.bmp /y
  GOTO OK
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
IF /I '%BRAND%'=='T' ( REN C:\U.bmp V.bmp /y  & GOTO OK )
IF /I '%BRAND%'=='M' ( REN C:\W.bmp X.bmp /y  & GOTO OK )
IF /I '%BRAND%'=='P' ( REN C:\Y.bmp Z.bmp /y  & GOTO OK )
```

Comment: Works great, thank you!  Now is there a way I can take this a step further?  I need to rename 2 files THEN GOTO.

Comment: `IF /I '%BRAND%'=='T' ( REN C:\U.bmp V.bmp /y  & **another command here** & GOTO OK )`
As you can see, use the & to separate the commands. But for clarity, i would prefere the way  @aphoria described below.